# Spring Boot/Kotlin maven project building using buildpacks fails with "./mvnw: permission denied"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, github, google-cloud-platform, buildpack

I'm trying to build and deploy Spring Boot/Kotlin maven project in Google Cloud. I'm using buildpacks and my project location is GitHub. It fails with the following error:

> [builder] Failure: (ID: 7d0b3ca3) executing command "./mvnw clean package --batch-mode -DskipTests -Dhttp.keepAlive=false --quiet": fork/exec ./mvnw: permission denied

More build logs:

> ................ Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
> From https://github.com/i-blast/photo-backend  * branch
> 641e09a5803cdf078ab64ac47f84809dd33bbc2f -> FETCH_HEAD HEAD is now at
> 641e09a fix: Replace output image analysis response to std in with
> logger output BUILD Pulling image: gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack Using
> default tag: latest latest: Pulling from k8s-skaffold/pack Digest:
> sha256:410a0f8a63d42b0c5ac800ba9c71789fcbffbf4fc4691a109e2883e3a365b629
> Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack:latest
> gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack:latest latest: Pulling from
> buildpacks/builder ................ Digest:
> sha256:ac0c5fdf12f61aada2fcf210e72c7c1bd7c99f7b685e5f5f9ad3ee318bd218df
> Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:latest
> v1: Pulling from buildpacks/gcp/run ................ Digest:
> sha256:e7ca52efe350a88d38050cc442bfd7013f2297affb2d37115815d7b5a3c616ad
> Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/buildpacks/gcp/run:v1
> 0.13.3: Pulling from buildpacksio/lifecycle ................ Digest: sha256:9d194fc3997e8c448473431433908d932cd359b10b270f2b0f76ec795c8cae28
> Status: Downloaded newer image for buildpacksio/lifecycle:0.13.3
> ===> DETECTING [detector] 4 of 5 buildpacks participating [detector] google.java.runtime    0.9.1 [detector] google.java.maven      0.9.0
> [detector] google.java.entrypoint 0.9.0 [detector] google.utils.label
> 0.0.2
> ===> ANALYZING [analyzer] Previous image with name "gcr.io/photo-backend-application/github.com/i-blast/photo-backend:641e09a5803cdf078ab64ac47f84809dd33bbc2f"
> not found
> ===> RESTORING
> ===> BUILDING [builder] === Java - Runtime (google.java.runtime@0.9.1) === [builder] Using latest Java 11 runtime version. You can specify a different version with GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION:
> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks#configuration
> [builder]
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [builder] Running "curl --fail --show-error --silent --location
> [https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v3/assets/feature_releases/11/ga?architecture=x64&heap_size=normal&image_type=jdk&jvm_impl=hotspot&os=linux&page=0&page_size=1&project=jdk&sort_order=DESC&vendor=adoptopenjdk"](https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/v3/assets/feature_releases/11/ga?architecture=x64&heap_size=normal&image_type=jdk&jvm_impl=hotspot&os=linux&page=0&page_size=1&project=jdk&sort_order=DESC&vendor=adoptopenjdk%22)
> [builder]  [builder] [ [builder]     { [builder]         "binaries": [
> [builder]             { [builder]                 "architecture":
> "x64", [builder]                 "download_count": 429925, [builder]
> "heap_size": "normal", [builder]                 "image_type": "jdk",
> [builder]                 "jvm_impl": "hotspot", [builder]
> "os": "linux", [builder]                 "package": { [builder]
> "checksum":
> "43fb84f8063ad9bf6b6d694a67b8f64c8827552b920ec5ce794dfe5602edffe7",
> [builder]                     "checksum_link":
> "https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz.sha256.txt",
> [builder]                     "download_count": 429925, [builder]
> "link":
> "https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz",
> [builder]                     "metadata_link":
> "https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz.json",
> [builder]                     "name":
> "OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz", [builder]
> "size": 193110496 [builder]                 }, [builder]
> "project": "jdk", [builder]                 "scm_ref":
> "jdk-11.0.14.1+1_adopt", [builder]                 "updated_at":
> "2022-02-10T12:35:32Z" [builder]             } [builder]         ],
> [builder]         "download_count": 992972, [builder]         "id":
> "MDc6UmVsZWFzZTU5MjI2NDAx.+ZQeBQqN7lfK6A==", [builder]
> "release_link":
> "https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/tag/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1",
> [builder]         "release_name": "jdk-11.0.14.1+1", [builder]
> "release_type": "ga", [builder]         "source": { [builder]
> "link":
> "https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-sources_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz",
> [builder]             "name": "OpenJDK11U-sources_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz",
> [builder]             "size": 123673644 [builder]         }, [builder]
> "timestamp": "2022-02-10T12:24:13Z", [builder]         "updated_at":
> "2022-03-07T14:41:37Z", [builder]         "vendor": "eclipse",
> [builder]         "version_data": { [builder]             "build": 1,
> [builder]             "major": 11, [builder]             "minor": 0,
> [builder]             "openjdk_version": "11.0.14.1+1", [builder]
> "patch": 1, [builder]             "security": 14, [builder]
> "semver": "11.0.14+101" [builder]         } [builder]     } [builder]
> ]Done "curl --fail --show-error --silent --location
> https://api.ado..." (382.570374ms) [builder] Installing Java
> v11.0.14+101 [builder]
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [builder] Running "bash -c curl --fail --show-error --silent
> --location --retry 3 https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz
> | tar xz --directory /layers/google.java.runtime/java
> --strip-components=1" [builder] Done "bash -c curl --fail --show-error --silent --location --retry..." (4.184067234s) [builder] === Java - Maven (google.java.maven@0.9.0) === [builder]
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [builder] Running "./mvnw clean package --batch-mode -DskipTests
> -Dhttp.keepAlive=false --quiet" [builder] Done "./mvnw clean package --batch-mode -DskipTests -Dhttp.keepAli..." (860.796µs) [builder] Failure: (ID: 7d0b3ca3) executing command "./mvnw clean package
> --batch-mode -DskipTests -Dhttp.keepAlive=false --quiet": fork/exec ./mvnw: permission denied [builder]
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [builder] Sorry your project couldn't be built. [builder] Our
> documentation explains ways to configure Buildpacks to better
> recognise your project: [builder]  ->
> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/blob/main/README.md
> [builder] If you think you've found an issue, please report it:
> [builder]  ->
> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/new [builder]
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [builder] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
>
> ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle. This may be the result of
> using an untrusted builder: failed with status code: 51 ERROR ERROR:
> build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack" failed: step exited with
> non-zero status: 1

Comment: The file `mvnw` in your project does not have the right execution permission...You have to change them... via `chmod +x mvnw`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **khmarbaise** - this solved the issue:

> git update-index --chmod=+x mvnw

and then pushing changes to repository.